# How can I find where a Mysql function is used?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I'm using Mysql 8. There is a function called `calculateGP` used in one of the viewes I'm working on. I want to modify this function but I'm not sure if the function is used elsewhere in the database. Is there a query that I can run to know where else the function is referenced in the database?

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: I ended up taking a structural mysql dump and searching for the function name in the script to find the occurrences.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Modifying the function can cause other views that may be using the same function, to break/modify their result. Not want to cause unintentional results in those views

Comment: @Kasun You can add that as an answer to your own question, and you will be allowed to accept it as the accepted answer in a few days. That way, the question doesn't get listed in the unanswered question lists :)

Comment: will do. However it is an alternative method not a direct solution to the question. I'll keep that method as the accepted answer until someone can provide a better one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
WHERE VIEW_DEFINITION LIKE '%`calculateGP`%'
```

This might find false matches if you have tables or columns or other identifiers that are also named `calculateGP`.

Comment: Nice, this gives the view names which use the function. Just need to make sure to run the query with enough privileges to see all view definitions in `information_schema.VIEWS` table. Also can see if any triggers are using the function by running the same query on `ACTION_STATEMENT` column in `information_schema.TRIGGERS` table.

Comment: to check if it is being used in another function or procedure, can use the `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` column in `information_schema.ROUTINES` column

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find references to the function `calculateGP` by taking a MySQL structural dump of the database and by doing a text search on the dump file. This is an alternative method of finding the references in the database without running a MySQL query to do so.